# (??) GDPR extension ver. 2.8 issue? (from 5.18.2 to 5.22 CiviCRM ver.)

Tags: wordpress, gdpr

We manage CiviCRM for some NPO in SaaS mode. We noticed that probably the GDPR extension ver. 2.8 has some problems.

Indeed on:

- Wordpress 5.3.2
- both on PHP ver. 7.3 and ver. 7.2
- both whit PHP-FPM and Fast-CGI compression
- PHP open_basedir both enabled and disabled
- MySQLversion: 10.3.22-MariaDB-0 + deb10u1
- on all CiviCRM ver. from 5.18.2 to 5.22

a simple export to .csv of only 2000 contacts (only Name, Surname, Email) takes at least 200 seconds and causes the host down (if it is set to the canonical 100s  Time Over)

We also have the feeling that everything is going a little slower, especially to access CiviCRM at the first connection

With version 2.7 of the GDPR Extention the same operation closes correctly on 3 seconds.

Can anyone check if he has this problem?

Comment: Might be worth asking on the GDPR extension issue queue as well

Comment: I post on https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/issues but... no one has yet taken on the problem   :(